# youtube video will not display in desktop Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, youtube

Youtube video does not show up in a modal window when viewed in a desktop version of Chrome. The modal window pops up but the youtube video does not.

https://animalhealth.pfizer.com/sites/pahweb/US/EN/Products/Pages/ClarifideStories.aspx

It works in IE and Firefox on Windows7, works in Chrome on Android ICS and iOS6 iPad.

It is on a sharepoint site

but if I open a version saved to my desktop it works fine in chrome.

I am using jquery fancybox

How it is called

```
    <a class="iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?  v=nGAyZSFDYh0&feature=player_embedded#at=41" style=" float: left;">


javascript
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".iframe").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting that it has to do with your secure `HTTPS` page calling a non-secure `HTTP` page. 
Try changing your youtube videos to `https://www.youtube.com/. . . . .`

Answer (score 0):

In the other browsers the video plays at the beginning, so it may be the start sequence: `#at=41`that is causing issue along with the embed option. If you don't intend to start at 41 seconds might as well take it out, or use the `youtube.com/embed/videoid` option.